# does java support unicode wildcard?

Tags: java, regex, unicode, wildcard

I found this in an online tutorial produced in 2011:

> Unicode wildcard: \X only supported in Perl and PHP

Does Java support unicode wildcard nowadays?

Comment: I do not think so. Probably, you may rely on `(?:[\0-\t\x0B\f\x0E-\u2027\u202A-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFF]|[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]|[\uD800-\uDBFF](?![\uDC00-\uDFFF])|(?:[^\uD800-\uDBFF]|^)[\uDC00-\uDFFF])` to match the same in Java.

Comment: According to [regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#grapheme) you can use `\P{M}\p{M}*+` as a reasonably close substitute for `\X` in Java

Comment: What I know in Unicode is that all characters are not encoded in the same way and it does create some problems for regular expression engines. Could someone tell me what are my options to solve this kind of problem in java?

Comment: @hamzabelmellouki You already have 2 solutions :)